# html - distribute five images horizontally across container?

Tags: html, css

I have div container and five images inside it. I need to distribute them within the container (it has dynamic width) so that the spacing between the images is the same, and the left image is justified to the left, and the right image is justified to the right.

**UPD:**
Images must have fixed width (for example 100px), but container div is more than 500px.

Comment: i think you should look up this problem again as it is a very common problem

Answer (score 1):

Keep all the images in `div`'s and then give `width: 20%;`, `min-width:100px;`,`text-align: center` and `float:left` /`display: inline-block` to those `div` elements. This should solve the problem.

```
div container
   --> div (5)
     --> images (5)
```

For your first child element, use `:first-child` pseudo class and for last child element, use `:last-child` pseudo class and then give `text-align :left` and `text-aling: right` respectively.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div><img src="https://www.google.com.au/images/srpr/logo4w.png" /></div>
    <div><img src="https://www.google.com.au/images/srpr/logo4w.png" /></div>
    <div><img src="https://www.google.com.au/images/srpr/logo4w.png" /></div>
    <div><img src="https://www.google.com.au/images/srpr/logo4w.png" /></div>
    <div><img src="https://www.google.com.au/images/srpr/logo4w.png" /></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div>div {
    width:20%;
    float:left; /* display: inline-block; */
    min-width:100px; /* equal to the width of the image */
    text-align:center;
}

img{width:100px;}

div:first-child{text-align:left;}
div:last-child{text-align:right;}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FfAsk/1/)**

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FfAsk/9/)** (*Using javascript*)

Comment: It's ok, but spacing between images are not same. It's bigger between first and second and smaller between second and third.

Comment: Excuse me. It was russian. I was an error while copying it from Google Translate.

Comment: @BeerBrother sorry for thinking it as spam. I was not meant any disrespect to your language. :)

Comment: No, it is spaces before first and after last image, but i dont need space here. I know that it is not trivial :(

Comment: @BeerBrother do you know the width of the images? or is it in percentages?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27310/discussion-between-beer-brother-and-mr-green)

Comment: It's somewhere near the end, but again, the distance between the first image and the second is less than that between the second and third. I'm not the first day working on it and I think that will solve the problem using JavaScript.

Comment: @BeerBrother yes it will be easier with javascript. I will update my post using javascript.

Comment: @BeerBrother check this fiddle. http://jsbin.com/ajobiz/1/edit (done using javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `width:20%;` and `float;left;`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/FfAsk/)

```
img {
    width:20%;
    float:left;

    box-sizing:border-box;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

You can add `box-sizing:border-box` now and your `padding` and `border` sizes will be includes in your `width` so they won't overflow to the next line.